# using localtunnel\ngrok with more than one local site

Tags: javascript, node.js, ngrok, localtunnel

I have a web site that is spitted across to local servers, one for the front end, at localhost:3000 and one for the restapi that is on localhost:3001

I want to expose that dev environment using localtunnel or ngrok - but I don't know how to expose two sites at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With ngrok, you can do it by using a config file.

Here is my config file: `ngrok.yml`

```
tunnels:
  webSite:
    proto: http
    addr: 4200
    host_header: localhost
  dataApi:
    proto: http
    addr: 56557
    host_header: localhost
```

And here is the command I use to run it:

```
ngrok start -config ngrok.yml dataApi webSite
```

Hope it helps